# Как убрать баннер debug на экране Flutter-приложения

Tags: flutter, dart

Я пытаюсь сделать скриншот с помощью команды

```
flutter screenshot
```

И мне хотелось бы чтобы на нем не было баннера `debug` в правом верхнем углу, чтобы его(*скриншот*) можно было разместить в портфолио и магазине приложений.
Сейчас он присутствует на скриншоте.

Какие можно убрать данный баннер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893935/how-can-i-remove-the-flutter-debug-banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Для начала:**
>  данный баннер автоматически убирается при сборке билда для релиза приложения.

Если же вы хотите, чтобы он Вас не смущал во время процесса разработки и отладки, Вы можете проделать следующее:

При создании экземпляра `MaterialApp` (или `ScaffoldApp`) Вам необходимо установить флаг `debugShowCheckedModeBanner` в значение `false`

```dart
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
)
```

Либо тоже самое можно сделать и при инициализации `CupertinoApp`

```dart
CupertinoApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
)
```

Их (*одного из них*) как правило можно найти в файле main.dart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого данный баннер исчезнет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893964/4558866